# Execute process and Get Process output in realtime and update in UI in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android java app that pings a host address using ping command, and updates the output of the command. The output should be printed in real time as text view as each line added to a parent layout like linear layout.
Say you are going to ping google.com 4 times, the output should be printed
Every one second.
Eg the typical ping command output will be like this

```
PING google.com (142.250.195.78): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.195.78: icmp_seq=0 ttl=117 time=20.096 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.195.78: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=10.201 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.195.78: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=12.088 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.195.78: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=34.029 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 10.201/19.104/34.029/9.384 ms
```

I want the output to be printed as soon as the first line which is PING google.com (142.250.195.78): 56 data bytes ready

I have attempted to implement this using an Executor, updating the UI with each line of the ping command output and adding each line to a LinearLayout. However, I am getting the output as a whole rather than real time.

Below is my code

```
private void ping() {
    OutputLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            boolean isReachable = isAddressReachable(“google.com”, 1000);
            requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {

                if (isReachable) {
                    // do ping using the ping command and update the real time data here continuously
                    try {
                        isPingRunning = true;
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c  4 google.com“);

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && isPingRunning) {
                            final String finalLine = line; // To use inside runOnUiThread
                            requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                // Update UI with real-time data (finalLine)
                                if (finalLine.contains("bytes from")) {
                                    TextView textView = new TextView(requireContext());
                                    textView.setText(finalLine);
                                    OutputLinearLayout.addView(textView);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        process.waitFor();
                        process.destroy();
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("PING", "EXCEPTION");
                    } finally {
                        isPingRunning = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    // some error
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // some exception
        }
    });
}
```